# ffmpeg GPU use cuvid with hwdownload will never finished, Appeared only recently

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu

ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version N-97331-g10a68cc Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3)
  configuration: --pkg-config-flags=--static --prefix=/usr/local/ffmpeg --bindir=/usr/local/ffmpeg/bin --extra-cflags='-I /usr/local/ffmpeg/include -I /usr/local/cuda/include/' --extra-ldflags='-L /usr/local/ffmpeg/lib -L /usr/local/cuda/lib64/' --extra-libs=-lpthread --enable-cuda --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-libnpp --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-vaapi --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-libaom --enable-nvenc
```

nvidia-msi

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.82       Driver Version: 440.82       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1080    Off  | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   51C    P8    13W / 200W |     18MiB /  8119MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     23224      C   ffmpeg                                         8MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

if i use this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -threads 0 -loglevel debug -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -i 1.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -strict -2 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_npp=1280:-2" ouzz2t.mp4
```

it will very fast.

but if i use this command:

```
ffmpeg -re -threads 0 -loglevel debug -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -hwaccel_output_format cuda -hwaccel_device intel -i 1.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -c:a aac -ac 2 -b:a 128k -strict -2 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale_npp=1280:-2:format=yuv420p[tmp],[tmp]hwdownload,format=yuv420" ouzz2t.mp4
```

it will never finished, one 40MB mp4 will transcode 44 minutes and not finished.

as you see

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     23224      C   ffmpeg                                         8MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

it will only use GPU memory 8mib and top will show:

[image: screenshot from top]

debug log:

```
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded lib: libcuda.so.1
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuInit
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDeviceGetCount
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDeviceGet
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDeviceGetAttribute
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDeviceGetName
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDeviceComputeCapability
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuCtxCreate_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuCtxSetLimit
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuCtxPushCurrent_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuCtxPopCurrent_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuCtxDestroy_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMemAlloc_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMemAllocPitch_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMemsetD8Async
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMemFree_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMemcpy2D_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMemcpy2DAsync_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGetErrorName
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGetErrorString
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuCtxGetDevice
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDevicePrimaryCtxRelease
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDevicePrimaryCtxSetFlags
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDevicePrimaryCtxReset
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuStreamCreate
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuStreamQuery
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuStreamSynchronize
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuStreamDestroy_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuStreamAddCallback
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuEventCreate
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuEventDestroy_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuEventSynchronize
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuEventQuery
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuEventRecord
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuLaunchKernel
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuModuleLoadData
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuModuleUnload
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuModuleGetFunction
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuTexObjectCreate
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuTexObjectDestroy
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGLGetDevices_v2
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGraphicsGLRegisterImage
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGraphicsUnregisterResource
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGraphicsMapResources
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGraphicsUnmapResources
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuGraphicsSubResourceGetMappedArray
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDeviceGetUuid
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuImportExternalMemory
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDestroyExternalMemory
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuExternalMemoryGetMappedMipmappedArray
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMipmappedArrayGetLevel
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuMipmappedArrayDestroy
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuImportExternalSemaphore
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuDestroyExternalSemaphore
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuSignalExternalSemaphoresAsync
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x561cfaef92c0] Loaded sym: cuWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync
```

Stop at Loaded sym: cuWaitExternalSemaphoresAsync, and ffmpeg will always 100% cpu and never finished.

Appeared only recently, last week it work fine, but today it work worse.

Somebody knows what happens to me?